# C# EF, refresh context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm creating an app that should work with various sqlite databases (with same structure) and I want to be able to open and close different databases. I use EF6 and I just can't figure out how to open a different database file (and make EF to reload and use data from new file). There are many questions regarding this but none of them work for me.

this is my dbContext generated by EF

```
public partial class mainEntities : DbContext
    {
        public mainEntities()
            : base("name=mainEntities")
        {
        }
    ...
    }
```

this is how I use and try to update my context

```
class Db
{
    private static mainEntities myDbInstance;
    public static mainEntities MyDbInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (myDbInstance == null)
            {
                myDbInstance = new mainEntities();
            }
            return myDbInstance;
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateConnectionString(string pth)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;");
        sb.Append("provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;");
        sb.Append("provider connection string=");
        sb.Append("'");
        sb.Append("datetime format=JulianDay;");
        sb.Append("foreign keys=True;");
        sb.Append("data source=");
        sb.Append(pth);
        sb.Append("'");

        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");

        connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["mainEntities"].ConnectionString = sb.ToString();
        connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["mainEntities"].ProviderName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
        config.Save();
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

        //reset context - does not work
        MyDbInstance.Dispose();
        myDbInstance = null;            
    }
}
```

I am able to update the connectionString,

```
var conn_str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainEntities"].ConnectionString;
```

returns correct string after I change database file, but data is loaded from the original one.

**EDIT:**

I check if the connection changed with simple WPF GUI

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void refresh_labels()
    {
        var conn_str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainEntities"].ConnectionString;
        var rows_count =
        (from d in Db.MyDbInstance.TagsFiles
        select d).Count();

        label1.Content = conn_str.Split(';')[4];
        label2.Content = rows_count;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String DbFileName1 = @"c:\tmp\db1.db3";
        String DbFileName2 = @"c:\tmp\db2.db3";

        var conn_str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainEntities"].ConnectionString;
        if (conn_str.Contains(DbFileName1))
        {        
            Db.UpdateConnectionString(DbFileName2);                
        }
        else
        {        
            Db.UpdateConnectionString(DbFileName1);
        }
        refresh_labels();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a string builder? why you can just write a single string?

Comment: Add a second constructor accepting a connection string and initiate your contexts by it.

Comment: @johnny5 I think that StringBuilder is faster than concatenating strings. Obviously it does not make a difference here.

Comment: @GertArnold ok, so where do I use that connStr in the constructor?

Comment: `public mainEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)`

Comment: And use an `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: 1. Show us the code that isn't working where you load the data. 2. Show us the code that calls a change to the connection string. 3. You don't have to build it, it's a bunch of static text anyway, just put it in a single string without all that logic.

Comment: @storm_88 why are you even concatenating 7 strings... You only have 1 variable, you only need to concat 1 string

Comment: @GertArnold thanks but passing it in constructor raises UnintentionalCodeFirstException in void OnModelCreating() generated by EF. I used EF designer from database.

Comment: so far I managed to get it working only by restarting the app after changes in the connection string. I still wonder if it is possible to achieve without restart.